# JS Guarda en el LocalStorage Pero Ajax No envia Data

Tags: php, javascript

En el Index.php tengo un elemento html select para seleccionar distintos items llamado "comboEspecialidades" y en este mismo archivo un script js para almacenar en el LocalStorage y enviarlo a mi respuesta php por medio de `onclick= 'guardardatos ()'>`  del btn tipo submit del form:

```
<script type="text/javascript">


                  function guardardatos () {
                    var diaAusente = document.getElementById('comboEspecialidad').value;
                    localStorage.setItem('diaAusente', diaAusente);
                    var con = localStorage.getItem('diaAusente');
                    saved = con;
                    console.log('diaAusente');
                    alert(saved);

                  }

                  function local() {
                    var con = localStorage.getItem('diaAusente');
                    var saved = con;
                    $.ajax({
                      type: "POST",
                      url: "respuesta.php",
                      data: {data: saved},
                      dataType: 'json',
                      success: function(data) {

                     alert(data.mensaje);
                      },
                      error: function(error) {
                        alert(error);
                        console.log(error);
                      }
                    });
                  }

                </script>
```

y en mi archivo php respuesta.php para capturar 'data' lo siguiente:

```
if (isset ($_REQUEST['data'])){
echo (json_decode($data = $_REQUEST['data']));
echo $data;
}else{
echo "NADA HA LLEGADO";
  }
```

Si bien escribe la info en el localStorage  cuando me muestra la pagina respuesta.php no llega nada. solo "NADA HA LLEGADO"  no logro capturar lo que estoy enviando con el script js en el index.php. Desde ya muchas Gracias

Answer (score 0):

En realidad el código si está funcionando, el problema se debe a los `Headers`.

En tu petición especificas:

```
dataType: 'json',
```

Esta definición quiere decir que el servidor está obligado a responder en `JSON` o no se considerará una respuesta valida.

Mientras que en tu codigo `php` devuelves los datos de la siguiente manera:

```
echo $data;
```

Lo que se traduce en una respuesta de texto plano / html.

Para corregir el error simplemente debes asegurarte que el servidor responda en `JSON` o quitar el tipo de dato que esperas que devuelva en la consulta que realiza el ajax.

Para ello debes utilizar:

```
echo json_encode($data);
```

y también puedes definir el tipo de respuesta en el servidor agregando el siguiente header:

```
header('Content-Type: application/json');
```

**EJEMPLO PRACTICO FUNCIONAL**

**CLIENTE: index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Ejemplo ajax</h1>
    <pre class="code">
    </pre>
    <script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.js"
  integrity="sha256-WpOohJOqMqqyKL9FccASB9O0KwACQJpFTUBLTYOVvVU="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script>
        $(function(){
            var saved = 'Esta variable es creada en Javascript';
            $.ajax({
                      type: "POST",
                      url: "respuesta.php",
                      data: {data: saved},
                      dataType: 'json',
                      success: function(data) {
                        $('.code').text(JSON.stringify(data))
                        console.log("SUCCESS",data);
                      },
                      error: function(error) {
                        $('.code').text(JSON.stringify(error))
                        console.log("ERROR",error);
                      }
                    });
        })
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

**SERVIDOR: respuesta.php**

```
<?php
    // Definir el tiempo de respuesta
    header('Content-Type: application/json');
    // Permitir CORS
    header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
    header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST');
    header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: X-Requested-With");

    function ajax_response ($data = null, $error = false){
        $response = [
            'content' => $data,
            'error' => $error
        ];
        echo json_encode($response);
    }

    if (isset($_REQUEST['data'])){
        ajax_response($_REQUEST['data']);
    }else{
        ajax_response(null, true);
    }
```

Crea dos ficheros con los respectivos nombres y extensiones en la raíz de tu carpeta `htdocs`. Ingresa a tu servidor local en el navegador poniendo en la url `localhost`

Comment: César Alejando M Gracias por responder he hecho lo que me indicas pero sigue sin traer nada.

Comment: he cambiado : en respuesta.php   <?php 
header('Content-Type: application/json');

if (isset ($_REQUEST['data'])){
echo json_encode($data);

}else{
echo "NADA HA LLEGADO";
  }
?>

Comment: Le he sacado el dataType al ajax y sigue sin enviar nada a respuesta.php

Comment: @JuanPerez Yo he probado el código y me ha funcionado. ¿Estás ejecutando el codigo php dentro de un servidor? Al definir la ruta ````respuesta.php```` implica que tanto el fichero js como el php estén en el mismo nivel del directorio ¿Es así?

Comment: si..estoy ejecutando todo en Xampp y el script js esta en el mismo index.php . Por eso había posteado que el script js sí escribe en el localstorage pero si te fijas la funcion 'local' que es la que recupera y manda via Ajax al respuesta.php al parecer no funciona.  Index y respuesta están en el mismo nivel. ahora probé el script js ejecutarlo desde un archivo js y a Ajax le cambié la ruta pero tampoco funciona

Comment: Si te fijas en la pestaña network del navegador al inspeccionar elemento, el php responde bien o falla la conexión hacia el?

Comment: me fije en all y en los archivos todo figura ok o sea 200

Comment: @JuanPerez he agregado un ejemplo practico funcional, ¿Puedes probarlo?

Comment: mil disculpas por tardar en contestar mucho trabajo con esta Pandemia.Te agradezco mucho tu ayuda. Tu ejemplo si funciona pero al adpatarlo al mio no. No olvides que en mi index.php tengo la funcion Js que escribe en el localstorage y otra funcion que la recupera desde ah también Jsi. Mi funcion que escribe en el Localstorage anda perfecto pero  mi otra funcion que la recupera al parecer no. Quiza por eso no manda la info al server desde el localstorage

Comment: tengo que guardar el valor de la variable en el LocalStorage porque la pagina se refresca y cuando lo hace debe otra vez recuperar la info desde esa variable. Sino obtengo un Undefined